# VMWare Workstation: Automate Install and Deployment from vmdk

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am building a (manually)bootable .vmdk file, but would like to further automate the process by using the .vmdk to create all necessary VM files and make it boot.

How can I do this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was hoping for an elegant way to do this through an API, but the solution 
was as simple as creating a VM manually, then swapping out all file references in the generated files, and completely replacing the .vmdk.